# Typeahead and Tokenfield Like functionality in android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

The more I look into this, more and more confusing it gets (I think its because I am used to Twitter Bootstrap) - anyways, How do I do this on Xamarin Android?

The closest I got to find something was this https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/TagEntryView

Is there anything out there which can help me implement bootstrap like

- Typeahead
- Token Input

like functionality in Xamarin android

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android exists an AutoCompleteTextView control which could be something similar to your typeahead bootstrap functionality.

In general I found with a quick search this [library](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete). It looks easily to convert to C#.